# How to execute PowerShell Net MessageBox in cmd/batch

Tags: powershell, batch-file, cmd, messagebox

I have a batch file with lot of stuff. I there is one Alert Window with info for user.

On Windows Pro I'm using Msg command for it and it works fine.

On Windows Home there is no Msg, so I got the idea to use PowerShell instead:

```
[System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show("my text")
```

which works fine in PowerShell.

-However, when I try to use it in batch or execute it directly in Cmd, I only get the text:

```
  C:\Windows\System32>powershell {[System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show("\""my text"\"")}
    [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show("my text")
```

Or I get errors:

```
C:\Windows\System32>powershell -command [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show("my text")
At line:1 char:41
+ [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show(my text)
+                                         ~
Missing ')' in method call.
At line:1 char:41
+ [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show(my text)
+                                         ~~
Unexpected token 'my' in expression or statement.
At line:1 char:48
+ [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show(my text)
+                                                ~
Unexpected token ')' in expression or statement.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MissingEndParenthesisInMethodCall
```

or

```
     C:\Windows\System32>powershell -command "& {[System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show('my text')}"
Unable to find type [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox].
At line:1 char:4
+ & {[System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show('my text')}
+    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox:TypeName) [],
    RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : TypeNotFound
```

What should I do to get it to work?

(without rewriting the whole script to PowerShell, that is)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to load the type before you can invoke it. You can do this:

```
powershell -command "[reflection.assembly]::LoadWithPartialName('System.Windows.Forms')|out-null;[windows.forms.messagebox]::Show('my message')"
```

Answer (score 3):

As TheMadTechnician stated, you may need to load it first.

This is effectively the same answer as theirs just over a couple of lines:

```bat
@Echo Off
PowerShell -Command^
 "[Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName('System.Windows.Forms')|Out-Null;"^
 "[System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show(\"my text\")"
Pause
```

*…and whilst double quotes around `my text` is not necessary, I've used them to show you the escapes.*